# Unable to access apache2 virtual host by the servername

Tags: apache, ubuntu, virtualhost

I am trying to create a virtual host in apache2 running on VirtualBox guest OS is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. The following is the configuration of my virtualhost in /etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite.lo.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   Servername mysite.lo
   ServerAlias www.mysite.lo
   DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite.lo
</VirtualHost>
```

Settings in /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
172.16.17.146 mysite.lo
```

When i try to run `www.mysite.lo` from my host browser, the browser responds no resuts found. When I type the ip address  `172.16.17.146` then the browser successfully displays the content of mysite.lo. I would be grateful if someone can guide me on how to access the contents using the servername instead of ip adress. This is the [link](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2015/07/how-to-enable-and-run-multiple-websites-using-apache2-on-ubuntu-15-04/) I have used as a guide to create my virtual host. Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should add `www.mysite.lo` to `172.16.17.146` line, or run `mysite.lo` without `www.` from host browser.

Comment: Thanks figured it out by mistake right after posting my question here.